# sending polymer iron form data to firebase

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer

I want to send this form data to Firebase URL:

https://blazing-heat-759.firebaseio.com/senso/

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/">                  
<paper-input name="qty2" label="Quantity"></paper-input>
<paper-input name="cdate2" id="d2" type="date"></paper-input>
<button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push your data to a Firebase ref. Try to adapt from [this example](https://github.com/StickmanVentures/real-time-contact/blob/master/real-time-contact.html) for a contact form.